# Loop over files in a directory

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to loop over files in a directory with scss.

Is there a way to provide a directory, like `/icons/*.png` and then loop over each one, getting the name of the file?

Comment: No.. SCSS is not environment aware.. It has no logic to iterate through a directory.

Comment: Also SASS tag is wrong.. software as a ser4vice is not super cool style sheets ;]

Comment: Hover over SASS, you'll see its not software as a service.

Comment: tomatoes tomatoes! :D

Comment: What are you planning on doing with each image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone looking - this is not possible with Sass or compass itself. You would need to write an extension to interface with the files.